# sap.m.Input with Float type

Tags: javascript, sapui5

My requirement is to have a textbox that can accept only floating point numbers up to two decimals only.

How to fix below problems:

1. I am unable to type anything like 20.01 but I am able to type 20.10.
   So when you start typing 0 after decimal point, it doesn't let you
   do that.
2. When I start typing 66.66 -> after this if you press 6 one
   more time it starts rounding off the last decimal. My requirement is
   not to allow the user to type anything else after last two decimal
   digits.

Below is my code:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(), "myModel");
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("myModel").setProperty("/Amount")
var textbox = new sap.m.Input({
  valueLiveUpdate: true,
  type: "Number",
}).placeAt("content");
textbox.bindProperty("value", {
  path: "myModel>/Amount",
  type: new sap.ui.model.type.Float({
    minIntegerDigits: 1,
    maxFractionDigits: 2,
    groupingEnabled: false
  }, {
    minimum: 1,
    maximum: 2000
  })
});
textbox.attachValidationError(function(e) {
  e.getParameter("element").setValueState("Error");
  e.getParameter("element").setValueStateText(e.getParameter("message"));
});
textbox.attachParseError(function(e) {
  e.getParameter("element").setValueState("Error");
  e.getParameter("element").setValueStateText(e.getParameter("message"));
});
textbox.attachFormatError(function(e) {
  e.getParameter("element").setValueState("Error");
  e.getParameter("element").setValueStateText(e.getParameter("message"));
});
textbox.attachValidationSuccess(function(e) {
  e.getParameter("element").setValueState("Success");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have already done this, but have you looked at the [documentation samples](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.TypeFloat/preview)?
It looks like it should do what you want.
If not, you could always write a simple function that checks the Input's value against a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The sap.m.MaskInput control allows users to enter data in a specific format.

API : https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MaskInput.html

Sample : http://jsbin.com/haciwexako/1/edit?html,js,output

Demokit: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MaskInput/preview

Comment: This can be a good solution, however I have below issues: 1) I need data binding in place, I am unable to bind value property in MaskInput 2. how do I put a min and max limits to the number entered?